# Help regarding Quadratic Sieve

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization, quadratic-residues, sieve-theory

I'm working on a code that recovers/retraces the prime no's from which a 30-digit number was formed. As, this is a factorization problem I have started regarding various algorithms about it. This brought me to Quadratic sieve. I know about the selection of B-smooth value and how to generate prime numbers which are less than B and have their Legendre symbol 1. Its the sieving step that is way more confusing. It would be a great help if anyone could give me a glimpse of it.

Comment: Let us call the $\ 30$-digit number $\ N\ $. Then the idea of the quadratic sieve is to factor $\ x^2-N\ $ (or more generally $\ x^2-k\cdot N\ $, but apparently mostly k = 1 is used) for integer $x>\sqrt{N}$. If the result is $B$-smooth , it is a so-called relation. If we have enough relations, the final step is to find a combination of the relations leading to a non-trial congruence $$u^2\equiv v^2\mod N$$ "Nontrivial" means that $\ u\ne \pm v \mod N$. If such a non-trivial congruence can be found, we are done because $ \gcd(u-v,N)\ $ and $\ gcd(u+v,N)\ $ are non-trivial factors of $\ N\ $.

Comment: @Peter Thank you so much for clarifying this.